# deleteOne mongoose problem express and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this code in my main.app:

```
app.get('/admin_panel', isAdm, async (req, res)=>{
  var records = await add_joke.find({});
  res.render('admin_panel', { recs: records });
})
```

After this I have and ejs file called admin_panel with this code:

```
<% for(var i in recs){ %>
          <div class="the_div_of_joke mt-5">
            <p class="titleOfJoke text-center"><%= recs[i].title %></p>
            <p class="glumaAdev text-center"><%= recs[i].description %></p>

            <a href="/profiles?username=<%= recs[i].post_user %>" class="text-right">By 
            <%=recs[i].post_user %></a>

            <form action="/admin_panel" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_post" value="<%= recs[i].id %>">
              <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>

          </div>
<% } %>
```

And that submit to delete is:

```
app.post('/admin_panel', async (req, res)=>{
   var the_records = req.body;
   console.log(the_records);
   var the_alg_find = await add_joke.deleteOne({id: the_records.id_post});
   console.log(the_alg_find);
   res.redirect('/admin_panel');
})
```

The problem is that that post form gives me the rest of the id  of the first post in the database to all post, it's there another method to select a specific item from an iteretion like this example?
Thank you!

Comment: Do the records really have different "id", or are they the same?

Comment: Here is the collection: https://ibb.co/QMn1ZqG

Answer (score 0):

To better understand this you should probably share your collection schema

Comment: Schema: https://ibb.co/xjHVtGs

Comment: Thanks for sharing the schema. According to your schema, you have `{_id: ObjectId(), title: string, desc: string,...}` so in your HTML form you should use `value="<%= recs[i]._id %>"` instead

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot that you posted, the documents in the database do not have an `id` field. Therefore, you cannot refer to `recs[i].id`, and queries on `{ id: somevalue }` will not work. Did you mean to use the `_id` field, instead?